# What php libraries need to copy to windows system dir and why?

Tags: php, configuration, curl

As you know Apache couldn't load curl modules, when its dll's are not in windows system dir even when your php path exists in system variable PATH. I want to ask,

- why it could happen?
- do you know other examples of same behavior, when you need to copy anything in win dir?

ps,

- PHPIniDir "F:/php" <- is set
- PATH=F:/php
- php.ini is in F:/php and it successfully loaded

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me yet. I've never heard of PHP modules having to be in the Windows system directory. Can you elaborate a bit more on your problem?

Comment: check php.ini, setting extension_dir = "c:\yourpath"

Comment: extension_dir is set correctly.

Comment: makes no sense to me either. but i must admit i have no clue what microsoft is up to theese days xD

Comment: Make sure you are restarting your computer after you change your environment variables or they dont take effect.  You do not need anything in the windows dir.  You only need things in the PHP dir.

Comment: Yes, I restarted and have PATH=F:\php where ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll are. But still couldn't start curl module. If I moved them to windows dir, curl starts successfully. Got Windows XP SP3.

Comment: In some ancient combination of OS'es and WAMP's, you may need to copy `libmysql.dll` (and a few more maybe) too.

Answer (score 1):

never copy php files to widows folder:

1.- Add php to windows PATH

2.- change extension_dir to FULL PATH

3.- see phpinfo for more information, paths etc...

4.- to add module:
extension = module_name.dll in php.ini

good luck